# Cual es el error al contar los tag A?

Tags: javascript

```js
var totales = 0;
function buscarLinks(){
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("A");
var i=0,
    linkse=links.length;
for(;i<linkse;i++){
  if(links[i].href == 'prueba') totales++;
  
}
}
console.log(totales);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body onload="buscarLinks();">
  
  <a href="prueba">prueba real 1</a>
  <hr>
  <a href="http://gg">prueba FALSA</a>
  <hr>
  <a href="prueba">prueba real 2</a>
  
</body>
</html>
```

***Intento contar los tag A pero siempre me salen 0 , por qué?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error esta donde realizas la comparación:

`if(links[i].href == 'prueba')`
Al imprimir los `href` dentro del `for`

```
for(;i<linkse;i++){
  console.log(links[i].href)
}
/* imprime:
https://stacksnippets.net/prueba
http://gg/
https://stacksnippets.net/prueba
*/
```

por ende siempre será falsa la comparación `if(links[i].href == 'prueba')`

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

```
var totales = 0;
function buscarLinks(){
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("A");
    for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++){
      if(links[i].getAttribute('href') == 'prueba') {
          totales++;
      }
      console.log(totales);
    }
}
```

Lo que te estaba ocurriendo era que a parte de que la comparación siempre iba a ser incorrecta ya que `.href` te está devolviendo la `URL entera`, pero si recoges tan solo el atributo `href` te devolverá solamente `prueba`, y por otro lado haces el `console.log` en el momento en el que el **Script es cargado**, pero resulta que la función `buscarLinks()` es llamada una vez la página está cargada, por lo tanto siempre te `resultaba 0` ya que la función `buscarLinks()` todavía no había sido ejecutada.

Espero que sirva de ayuda.